# Vuetify v-menu navigate using Keyboard issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

When Try to navigate the menu using Keyboard and Hit enter it opens the submenu but when I hit enter again it closes the submenu. It should not open because there's another menu under the submenu.

Codepen: [Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/Moloth/pen/ZEBOzQP?editors=1010)

```html
<v-menu :close-on-content-click="false" :offset-x='isOffsetX' :offset-y='isOffsetY' :open-on-hover='isOpenOnHover' :transition='transition' :value="openMenu">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn v-if='icon' :color='color' v-on="on">
          <v-icon>{{ icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-list-item v-else-if='isSubMenu' class='d-flex justify-space-between' v-on="on">
          {{ name }}<div class="flex-grow-1"></div><v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-btn v-else :color='color' v-on="on"  @click="openMenu = true"  text >{{ name }}</v-btn>
  </template>
  <v-list>
      <template v-for="(item, index) in menuItems">
              <v-divider v-if='item.isDivider' :key='index' />
              <dan-menu v-else-if='item.menu' :key='index' :name='item.name' :menu-items='item.menu' @dan-menu-click='emitClickEvent' :is-open-on-hover=false :is-offset-x=true :is-offset-y=false :is-sub-menu=true />
              <v-list-item v-else :key='index' @click='emitClickEvent(item)'>
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
      </template>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: it's an expected behavior and is programmed to do so do you have a problem? i looked at the codepen and it does what it is supposed to do

Comment: @TachibanaShin try to navigate using only keyboard Key, you cannot go to sub menu of submenu

Comment: Can I record the video again? codepen works properly when I open it

Comment: @TachibanaShin Click the button the navigate in to the menu using keyboard. you cannot go to the 3rd level of submenu when using Enter key.